# Swiper.js prevents me from implementing a flip transition, what is the specific javascript or css code preventing this?

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

I'm trying to implement code in which it slides like https://swiperjs.com/demos/110-slides-per-view/core (with arrows, which are easy to implement), and has the flipping functionality.
However, it seems like swiper.js interferes with the code that is supposed to work. Is the css or javascript of the flip function interfering with the code?

The flip functionality is working, but the slides aren't.

```
Html/CSS

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>locationtemplate</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="swiper-bundle.min.css">

        <style>
    * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
        
.card {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    transition: all .5s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
.front {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    background:#36732A;
    
}
.card.flipCard {
    transform:rotateY(-180deg);
}
.back {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
        -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;

}
.back {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    background: #2D63A9;
}

    </style>

</head>

<body>

<!--    <script>
            const mult = document.getElementById("bodyh");
        searchCities();
        
    async function searchCities() {

            const res = await fetch("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/millbj92/US-Zip-Codes-JSON/master/USCities.json");
            const cities = await res.json();

        var pic = "";
        cities.forEach( function(value){

        if (value.zip_code == 91030 )
        {
            pic = value.city;
        }                   

}        );
            
            let matches = cities.filter(element => {
                if(element.city === pic){
                    return element.city;
                }
            });
        outputHTML(matches);
        }
                       let arr = [];
                       var xmlhttp;
        const outputHTML = matches => {
            if(matches.length > 0){
                
                const html = matches
                .map(
                    map => {
                        
        
                        
                    }
                                

                    

        )
                .join('');
            
                } else {
                    mult.innerHTML = "<p>Don't see your city? Email us at localyco@gmail.com</p>";
                }
            
                                        
            };


    </script>

-->
        <!--    <h1>91030</h1>
        
<div class="locationhomepage" id ="91030"> -->
        <div class="swiper swiper3">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
            <div class="swiper-cards">

        <div class="card" id="1">
<div class="front"> <button onClick="flipOmelette(1)">Hello</button> <p>hello</p></div><div class="back"><p>hello</p> <button onClick="flipOmelette(1)">Hello</button></div>
        </div></div>
                <div class="swiper-cards">

        <div class="card" id="2">
<div class="front"> <button onClick="flipOmelette(2)">Hello</button> <p>hello</p></div><div class="back"><p>hello</p> <button onClick="flipOmelette(2)">Hello</button></div>
        </div></div>
            <div class="swiper-cards">

        <div class="card" id="3">
<div class="front"> <button onClick="flipOmelette(3)">Hello</button> <p>hello</p></div><div class="back"><p>hello</p> <button onClick="flipOmelette(3)">Hello</button></div>
        </div></div>
            <div class="swiper-cards">

        <div class="card" id="4">
<div class="front"> <button onClick="flipOmelette(4)">Hello</button> <p>hello</p></div><div class="back"><p>hello</p> <button onClick="flipOmelette(4)">Hello</button></div>
        </div></div>
            </div>
        
        <div class="swiper-button-next swiper-navBtn"></div>
            <div class="swiper-button-prev swiper-navBtn"></div>
            </div>
    <!--    
    </div> -->  </body> </html>
```

Javascript

```
 <script src="swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        let flip;
    function flipOmelette(hello){
         flip = document.getElementById(hello.toString());
        flip.classList.toggle("flipCard");
        console.log(hello);
    }
     var swiper3 = new Swiper('.swiper3', {
        slidesPerView: 10,
        spaceBetween: 2500,
         loop: true,
        spaceBetween: 300,
      
         navigation: {
      nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
      prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev",
    },
    });
    
    </script>
```

I tried the code above, which should have worked, but I'm probably missing something. Maybe the reason it's not working is because it's mainly for mobile applications.
The Flip is working, but the slides aren't.